# Angular 4 losing subscription with router paramMap using switchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing

Using the latest version of Angular I have a very small, simple application - see below:

[image: simple app]

The forecast detail component looks like the following:

```
public getForecastData(forecastId) : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>('/api/forecasts/' + forecastId + '/data');
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap(
      params => {
        return this.getForecastData(params.get('id'))
      })
})
.subscribe( (data) => {
  // business logic here
});
```

The issue I'm having is that if the getForecastData call fails (server returns 500) the subscription to the router paramMap observable seems to be lost. I try navigating to a different forecast and the getForecastData method is not called.

I imagine I need some kind of error handling but where do I need to handle this? adding the error call inside of the subscribe doesn't seem to work unless I need to be returning another Observable?

This is basically an adaptation from the tutorial on the Angular site however they are returning a Promise with static data and very much sticking to the happy path.

Comment: `data => {// business logic here}),
                err => //your error`
If you want to use this again in error would suggest ngOnIt >> call function>>error>> do function again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observables which error will signal `unsubscribe` upstream and propagate the error downstream. So when your getForecastData() call returns an error this is sent to your `subscribe` and unsubscribing upstream. That is the reason why your outer stream (the `switchMap`) stops.

If you want your stream to continue even if the `getForecastData` throws an error you need to catch it and return a regular value. For instance:

```
this.route.paramMap
.switchMap((params) => {
   return this.getForecastData(params.get('id')
    .do(null, err => console.log('getForecastData error: ' + err.message))
    .catch(_ => Rx.Observable.empty());
})
.subscribe();
```

[In this talk by Ben Lesh errors & handling them is explained in detail.](https://youtu.be/1vR9lQLfqjo?t=25m17s)